# How to prevent duplicate records in crystal reports version 13

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Image for duplicate records
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRbEg.jpg]

How to prevent duplicate records in crystal reports version 13

Comment: Please take the [tour] and look at [ask].

Answer (score 0):

Either fix up your source data to eliminate dupes, or group by Product Code.  IF the Qty and Total Amount are also duplicates, use the MAX instead of SUM on the group footer row.